# update sql relacionando uma coluna com valor externo

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

Bom dia,
Estou com uma dificuldade para fazer um update do SQL Server.
Eu tenho a seguinte situação:

**Tabela 1**

```
ID
Codigo
```

**Tabela 2**

```
ID
Nome
```

E eu tenho um arquivo excel assim:

**Excel**

```
Codigo
Nome
```

Eu preciso atualizar a coluna **Nome** da **Tabela 2**, com os dados do **excel**, qual seria querry nessa situação?

Eu tentei isso:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabela2 F
FULL JOIN Tabela1 M ON F.id = M.codigo
```

Comment: Qual a relação entre `Tabela1` e `Tabela2`?

Comment: Oi e bem-vindo, tentou alguma coisa? pelo menos mostre algum esforço.

Comment: A coluna ID, eu tentei isso 
select * from Tabela2 F full join Tabela1 M on F.id = M.codigo
Mas apresentou erro de overflow

Comment: Por favor, mostre dados de amostra e resultados esperados, e você está tentando atualizar a tabela de um arquivo excel ou o quê?

Comment: (1) A relação entre as tabelas `Tabela 1` e `Tabela 2` ocorre pelas colunas ID? (2) Qual é a extensão do arquivo que contém a planilha: xls ou xlsx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acho que você está procurando por `inner join`:

```
SELECT T2.Nome,
       T1.Codigo
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE --outras condições
```

Para inserir os dados do arquivo do excel:

```
SELECT * INTO nome do arquivo
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=nome do arquivo.xlsx', [página$]);
```

Se você estiver procurando por uma atualização ao juntar as duas tabelas:

```
UPDATE T2
SET Nome = 'NOME'
FROM [Tabela 2] T2
INNER JOIN [Tabela 1] T1 on T2.ID = T1.id
WHERE T2.Codigo = 'CODIGO'
```

Comment: Bem, isso não resolve a situação do OP. Ele quer saber como fazer um UPDATE, usando os dados do Excel.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, eu até consigo fazer esse inner join, mas aonde eu colocaria uma where? Pq eu ainda preciso co-relacionar a coluna Codigo, com a Coluna ID na tabela 2.

Comment: Olha o comentário dele

Comment: Eu não consigo pensar em uma sintaxe que co-relacione as duas tabelas, e eu consiga dar um update apenas nos Codigos que eu preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui com a seguinte situação

```
update Tabela 2
set Nome = '**NOME**'
from Tabela 2 A
INNER JOIN Tabela 1 B on B.ID = A.id
where B.Codigo = '**CODIGO**'
```

Como os valores estão em um arquivo excel eu preciso atualizar uma situação em uma tabela do SQL, eu vou precisar fazer manualmente essa querry para cada update que eu precisar atualizar.
Os valores **NOME**, **CODIGO** estão no excel.
Pelo próprio excel eu consigo fazer uma estrutura de CONCATENATE, que ira meio que prepara as querrys.
Obrigado pelas dicas, e pela atenção!

Comment: Não consegui ver na sua solução o uso dos dados do Excel. Acredito que sua resposta esteja incompleta para outras pessoas que venham futuramente a procurar uma solução.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara em tudo @Andrew Paes

Comment: @Sami o OP diz que precisa atualizar a coluna Nome da Tabela 2, com os dados do excel. Na query dele não está mostrando de onde estão vindos os dados do Excel. De onde vem?

Comment: @AndrewPaes Eu estou manualmente pegando os valores do excel, e fazendo um trabalho manual. Eu atualizei ve se fico mais claro.

Comment: Eu acho que ele só quer dizer que os dados foi carregá-lo a partir do arquivo excel @Andrew Paes

Comment: Bem, eu teria feito um BULK INSERT usando o Excel, e posteriormente feito um relacionamento entre as tabelas procurando na Tabela 2 somente quem precisa ter sue nome atualizado, no caso aqueles que divergem do Excel, pensando que isso poderia ser um processo automato.